# Decomposing an upper triangular Toeplitz matrix into a product of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Skirting the boundaries of being too broad a question, is there any *nice* way of decomposing a matrix structured as shown below into a product of two or more matrices?

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & \dots & v_n \\
  0 & v_1 & v_2  & \dots & v_{n-1} \\
  0 & 0 & v_1  & \dots & v_{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots &v_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a special name for such matrices? Where can I read more about them?

Comment: Why even decompose it? What is the motivation?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I was working on a problem that involved diagonalizing circulant matrices (which I recently learnt about) and I was trying to extend the result to other transforms similar to the Fourier transform, which is where I encountered the above matrix. Maybe I should have mentioned the motivation in the question, I was afraid it would not really help with clarifying things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an upper triangular Toeplitz matrix. Probably "Toeplitz" is the first word to use in your search for further information.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786108/explicit-formula-for-inverse-of-upper-triangular-toeplitz-matrix-inverse), for instance, is a reference about inverting such matrices, and [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40574-015-0031-3) is an article about factorizing them.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.