# Name of a specific upper-triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, toeplitz-matrices

What is the name (if any does exist) of an upper-triangular matrix whose elements on each diagonal are equal? Also, are there any properties associated with this matrix or not?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: They are a constant multiple of *unipotent matrices*, which are matrices $A$ such that $A-I$ is nilpotent, i.e. $(A-I)^{m} = O$ for some $m>0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about upper triangular Toeplitz matrices.  [Here is a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786108/81360) about inverting them, and [here is an article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40574-015-0031-3) about factorizing them.

It is notable that every such matrix can be written as a polynomial of the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\&&\ddots&\ddots&\\ &&&&1\\ &&&&0}
$$
and that any two such matrices commute.